# Travel time map to closest point using OSMnx

Tags: python, osmnx

I would like to make a travel time map that shows the minimum travel time to ANY point using OSMnx. My main question is what the best strategy is to go about this on a scale of a state or even a country. In the example below I focus on the state of Jalisco in Mexico.

So far, I've been able to (using some really nice examples) calculate the travel time for any location on the world to **one** particular point. The map then looks like this:
[image]

Now, I would like to make travel time map within a certain boundary (shapefile) which shows the minimum travel time to **any** point. In other words, the travel time to the point that is most accessible/lowest travel time. How I imagine this to look like is that for each node you calculate the travel time to the nearest points and then get the minimum travel time of those. Anyone knows how to best go about this? Below is an image of my region of analysis, Jalisco, Mexico.

This is my code which calculates the travel time from neighboring nodes to each coordinate. This is thus NOT able to make 1 combined travel time map to each closest/quickest point:

```
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import contextily as ctx

directory = Path.home() / "Dropbox (52impact)" / "52projects" / "GreySat (ESA)" / "WasteModel" / "Data" / "Test_StackOverflow"

# Enter GDF data
Points = gpd.read_file(directory / "Points_Jalisco.shp")
Jalisco = gpd.read_file(directory / "Adm2_Jalisco.shp").dissolve()

# Load OSM data from gdf
G = ox.graph_from_polygon(Jalisco.geometry.iloc[0], network_type="drive_service")

for coord in Points.geometry:
    print(coord)
    
    # First find nearest node to each Point
    nearestNode = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X = coord[1], Y = coord[0])
    
    # add travel time based on maximum speed
    G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G) 
    G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G) 
     
    # find travel times and route to each node in network
    (travel_times, routes) = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G, nearestNode, weight="travel_time")
    
    # set travel_time in minutes as attribute to each network node
    for node_id in travel_times:
        G.nodes.get(node_id)["travel_time"] = travel_times[node_id]/60
        
    # get nodes and edges as Geo data frame
    gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
    
    # find longest travel time 
    max_time_sec = max(travel_times.values())/60
    
    # define color scale using minimum and maximum travel times
    norm = mcolors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vcenter=max_time_sec/3, vmax=max_time_sec)
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    ax = plt.axes()
    # hide x and y axis
    ax.set_axis_off()
    
    # add colotbat showing travel time and corresponding colour
    cb = fig.colorbar(cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap="jet"), 
        ax=ax, orientation='horizontal')
    
    # plot each node with color indicating travel time
    gdf_nodes.plot(ax=ax, 
        column="travel_time", cmap="jet", norm=norm, s=10, alpha=.5)
    
    # add basemap with location labels
    ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLines, alpha=.3)
    ctx.add_basemap(ax, source=ctx.providers.Stamen.TonerLabels)
    
    cb.set_label('Driving time in minutes', fontsize = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow is to help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice.

Comment: Right, but is there any place for this? Just any hint to a thread or article would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks. I've spent the last 2 days on trying different ways to go about this question. Since each options has it's own drawbacks, I was actually motivated to take a step back for this thread. Difficult line to navigate

Comment: You might consider [pandana](https://udst.github.io/pandana/) for fast accessibility queries using contraction hierarchies.